# Semi-transposing a table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, transpose

I am having trouble semi-transposing the table below based on the 'LENGTH' column.  I am using an Oracle database, sample data:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+------+
| PERSON_ID | PERIOD_ID | LENGTH | FLAG |
+-----------+-----------+--------+------+
|         1 |         1 |      4 |    1 |
|         1 |         2 |      3 |    0 |
|         2 |         1 |      4 |    1 |
+-----------+-----------+--------+------+
```

I would like to lengthen this table based on the LENGTH row; basically duplicating the row for each value in the LENGTH column.

See the desired output table below:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------+------+
| PERSON_ID | PERIOD_ID | NUMBER | FLAG |
+-----------+-----------+--------+------+
|         1 |         1 |      1 |    1 |
|         1 |         1 |      2 |    1 |
|         1 |         1 |      3 |    1 |
|         1 |         1 |      4 |    1 |
|         1 |         2 |      1 |    0 |
|         1 |         2 |      2 |    0 |
|         1 |         2 |      3 |    0 |
|         2 |         1 |      1 |    1 |
|         2 |         1 |      2 |    1 |
|         2 |         1 |      3 |    1 |
|         2 |         1 |      4 |    1 |
+-----------+-----------+--------+------+
```

I typically work in Posgres so Oracle is new to me.

I've found some solutions using the `connect by` statement but they seem overly complicated, particularly when compared to the simple `generate_series()` command from Posgres.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE subtracting `1` from `length` until `1` is reached should work. (In Postgres too, BTW, should you need something working cross platform.)

```
WITH cte (person_id,
          period_id,
          number_,
          flag)
AS
(
SELECT person_id,
       period_id,
       length number_,
       flag
       FROM elbat
UNION ALL
SELECT person_id,
       period_id,
       number_ - 1 number_,
       flag
       FROM cte
       WHERE number_ > 1
)
SELECT *
       FROM cte
       ORDER BY person_id,
                period_id,
                number_;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=14e3a4d4edb76ff742a3ce45f19b000b)